# How to get sub folders in TFS programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I tried with the following code to get a particular project.

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(_tfs.Uri);
var vsStore = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var project = vsStore.TryGetTeamProject(_selectedTeamProject.Name);
```

Now, I need to get sub folders(if present) for that project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.GetItems.aspx) method

```
vsStore.GetItems("$/TeamProjectName/*")
```

And to get more control you can use the `ItemSpec` property which [accepts a wildcard path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx#itemspec).

Comment: I am not getting the subfolders  of a project which I had selected when using `GetItems`. Instead, it showing the only one item as count and that too as `{Item instance 56230589
  ChangesetId: 852
  CheckinDate: 10/21/2010 11:09:58 PM
  ContentLength: 0
  DeletionId: 0
  DownloadUrl: 
  Encoding: -3
  HashValue: [0]
  InternalAttributes: [0]
  InternalPropertyValues: [0]
  IsBranch: False
  ItemId: 1438
  ItemType: Folder
  ServerItem: $/ProjectName
  TimeZone: 
  TimeZoneOffset: 
}`. Actually multiple folders present inside the folder that I had selected. Thanks

Comment: You're getting back the project root. You'll need to add the wildcard to get it's children. Forgot about that :).

Comment: To get all children and their children you can add the `RecursionType.Full`.

Comment: Thank You very much. Now, working perfectly as expected. I am getting all sub folders.